# Incomplete decryption of S/MIME mails using openssl cms

Tags: email, openssl, smime

We're receiving signed and encrypted mails from many senders. For most senders, the decryption with openssl works fine using the following command:

```
openssl cms -decrypt -recip <path-to-key> -in <path-to-email>
```

However, for some senders, the output still seems to be an encrypted mail. The output looks like this:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data;
        name=smime.p7m
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m

MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCABgkqhkiG9w0BBwGggCSA
<base64 continues>
tyVzAusE29WxvR13wWJaSHn4/ObV6pa0yboAenGZTTXhJVmhAAAAAAAAAA==
```

If I open the output file in Outlook, it shows the correctly decrypted mail, so I'm confident the certificate, etc. is correct.

Is it possible to use openssl to output the mail to text, so I can process it automatically using tools other than Outlook?

Comment: Does `-verbose` display any helpful messages? Is the output identical to the input?

Comment: Wrt _"Is it possible to use openssl to output the mail to text"_  -  Not sure what you are asking for - can you clarify, please?

Comment: Have you read https://superuser.com/questions/1500028/decrypting-p7m-file

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in specific Outlook versions in that the smime.p7m attachment is formatted as another S/MIME email with headers. It's more a less an attachment within an attachment (which should be the case).

However, it should be possible to decrypt the attachment by applying the same `openssl cms -decrypt` once more with the weird output of the first as its input.